# What do an empty value in "Mode" column mean in Get-ChildItem in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

When I lunch a simple `Get-ChildItem` in a powershell window, I got the list of my files.

It's say in the [online help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-6#parameters) that the letters in the Mode property can be interperted as follows:

```
l (link)
d (directory)
a (archive)
r (read-only)
h (hidden)
s (system)
```

But I've got some file that have a `"------"` in Mode property. Like this :

```
    Répertoire : C:\TEST\test1


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----       06/08/2019     15:55          93497 3074164-Imp.SLDPRT
-a----       06/08/2019     11:10         152082 3074165-Imp.SLDPRT
-a----       06/08/2019     11:10         227203 3074167-Imp.SLDPRT
-a----       06/08/2019     11:10          97963 3074169-Imp.SLDPRT
------       05/03/2018     10:08        1043242 3074180-Imp.SLDPRT
------       24/07/2017     22:57         158189 3074185-Imp.SLDPRT
```

What does that mean ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Archive bit means that the file has changed since the last archive or backup operation.  Have no flags set just mean the files is not a System, Hidden, or Read-Only file nor is it a Link or Directory and it has not changed since the last archive operation.

Comment: Indeed, when I save the file the "------" turns into a "-a----". Thanks